# Multipage environment in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, servlets

I have been developing an AJAX web application using GWT. I've read several blogs and forums about this question and left with no clear idea. I understand that GWT is an AJAX application, that supports only stand-alone web application. By stand-alone, I meant GWT to be a single web page that would suffice the user requirements. However the use case I have is pretty complex and I'm stuck in this use case that doesn't let me proceed.

**My usecase(s) goes like this:**

**Usecase #1:** There is an order entry form where user will enter a search string to search for a particular item. With GWT, I could display the result in a table (say celltable). However, when I click a column in the cellTable, I want the value of the column to be sent to the server and display another page that will display only the details of the selected column. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

**Usecase #2:** Let's say the web application I develop is called "InventoryControl" and I have different requirements such as:

1. display Available stock
2. display Order stock
3. display Manufactured unit

and Using Java servlets, I could just type http://localhost/availableStock?stockId=1234 on my browser to get the "Display available stock" for the given stockId and then http://localhost:orderStock?stockId=1234 to get the "display order stock" and similarly "display manufactured unit". Is the same possible using GWT? i.e. when I type http://localhost/availableStock?stockId=1234, is it possible to read the parameter being passed and then display the corresponding page?

If these are not meant to be guaranteed by GWT, should I stick with Plain old JAVA servlets/JSP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ashok - Please note, what filip suggests above does not require  multiple "pages" in the sense of additional html host pages. You can build a panel holding your display of the details, and swap it into the rootpanel of your host in the onSuccess() of your rpc call. The GWT history mechanism allows you to assign anchors to these "places" and provide a mechanism to map these anchors to specific display classes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

GWT already has a mechanism for handling multiple page applications. Have a look at [Activities and Places](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html). You can define each page as a place in your application, and use the GWT mechanism to go from place to place at any time. Using places also allows you to easily add tokens/query parameters to each "page", in an OO manner, without having to worry about populating/querying the URL directly. Have a good read of the link!